# Protect sheet with exception of a specific range based on cell color

Tags: google-apps-script

I'm very new to Google Sheets/App Script and I'm trying to do the following:

I have a google sheet with data in the range of A7:z100.  I have some conditional formatting set up in which if the column header has the word "Outlook", and the cells below it up to row 100 is blank, then it turns those cells yellow.  I want to allow users to update only those cells shaded in yellow, and have the non yellow ones locked.  Can someone please help me write a script that would do that?

Thank you
Roger

I tried searching on code examples for what I'm trying to do but couldn't find anything

Comment: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#protect()

Comment: I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand `the non yellow ones`. Do you want to protect the non yellow cells of only one column?

Comment: Hello, I have 8 columns that have yellow shaded cells.  I want these to be the only cells that are not protected.  I would you like the rest of the spreadsheet to be protected.